# How to Sync Books from Mac on Catalina

Tags: ipad, mac, catalina, books

I upgraded to macOS 10.15.3 and am having trouble syncing books from my Mac to iPad.

In the documentation I only see reference to iCloud. This would not be satisfactory to me.

Is there a way to sync my books like it was done through iTunes/Music?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly access the sync settings by opening Finder, then selecting the mobile device.

Additionally, the Books sync page is in iTunes/Music under sync settings.

[image]